# How does the Galois group act on $E[m]$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $K$ be a perfect field and $\bar{K}$ its algebraic closure and say the characteristic of $K$ is $0$. Suppose I have an elliptic curve over $K$. 
It (the book I am reading) says that the Galois group $G(\bar{K}/K)$ acts on $E[m]$ because: if $[m]P = O$ then
$$
[m](P^{\sigma}) = ([m]P)^{\sigma} = O^{\sigma} = O.
$$
I don't understand why the first equality is true. Any explanation is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you have your curve in some projective space, then he Galois group acts simply by acting on each coordinate of points.

Comment: The map $[m]$ is defined by polynomials with coefficients in $K$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I figured this was the case. Could you possibly explain this in the answer maybe for the simple case $m=2$ or something?

Comment: The addition of the group is defined in terms of taking tangents and so on, so the action of the Galois group preserves it.

Comment: In any case, the case $m=2$ is the only one you need, because for example $[3]$ is the composition of two instances of $[2]$.

Comment: Alternatively, you can show that addition on $E$ is compatible with the action of $G=\text{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$ by showing that the isomorphism $P\mapsto (P)-(O)\in Pic^0(E)$ is an isomorphism of $G$-modules, which is a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

$m\sigma(p)=\sigma(p)+...+\sigma(p)=\sigma(p+...+p)=\sigma(mp)=\sigma(\mathcal O)=\mathcal O $

we can explain how the Galois group $G(\bar{K},K)$ acts on $E[m]$ by form: 
We have
$$ 0\to E(\bar{K})[m]\to  E(\bar{K}) \to E(\bar{K})\to 0 $$
then 
$$ 0\to E({K})[m]\to  E({K}) \to  E({K}) \to Hom(G(\bar{K},K),E(\bar{K})[m])\to Hom(G(\bar{K},K),E(\bar{K}))\to ... $$

Comment: Can you explain the exact sequence? By $Hom$ I assume you mean $H^1$?